# Can I read åäö from wxWidget wxTextCtrl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In C++. I have a wxTexfield and want the user to input a swedish translation of a word.

Everything works until the user types å, ä or ö (utf8).
Converting wxString to utf8 is not the problem - the problem is i can not even get the text out of the field. For the rest of text i use (where ans is a ponter to the Textfield). Any Idea? For the other strings i just use and it works perfekt.

```
 std::string ch = std::string((ans->GetValue()));
```

Comment: What happens when you "can not get the text out of the field"? Is `ch` empty? If you change `std::string` into `wxString`, does it work differently then? In general, avoid implicit conversions between `wxString` and `std::string`, as they easily result in silent conversion errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert an arbitrary Unicode string to `std::string` without specifying the encoding. By default, the encoding is that of the current locale which, especially under Windows, is not necessarily UTF-8 which is what you almost certainly want to use precisely because the characters not representable in this encoding will be simply lost during conversion.

So the correct thing to do is to explicitly use `ans->GetValue().ToUTF8()` and then your `std::string` will contain UTF-8-encoded representation of your characters. Of course, you need to realize that the string won't be of length 1, even for a single character, so perhaps you need to use `std::wstring` instead.

P.S. In wxWidgets 3.1.5+ you also have `utf8_string()` directly returning `std::string`, so you can also use this one if you have a new enough version.